# Vector-06C Soviet home PC schematics

Tags: hardware, 8080

Looking for Vector-06C schematics in any form.

Comment: Eevblog might be a better platform for this request?

Comment: @Kartman I dontknow, this isa good place too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look in this [archive](http://vector06c.fdd5-25.net/info.html)...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Here.](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/vector06cc/vector-06c-schematics.djvu)

[For questions, you can try here (Russian).](https://zx-pk.ru/threads/8669-vektor-06ts-zhelezo.html)

[An article about a computer.](https://zx-pk.ru/content/136-Vektor-06C-sovetski-bog-tcveta-i-zvuka)

Comment: It is a link-only answer

Comment: @OmarL And yet you claim that the question is a good fit. The only possible answer is a link answer.

Comment: @pipe Not so; the circuit is in the public domain and so may be included here

Comment: I'm okay with this being a link-only answer.  Normally, the expectation is to summarize the link material, but schematics are not so easy to summarize in words.  Let it be.  @ayc: If this answers your question, be sure to click on the checkmark.

Comment: @DrSheldon The network rules, however, are not.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The question asks for a link only answer - everything would mean to assume why and for what he needs them. So either a link only answer is fine, then no reason to improve anything (beside the link text that is) here, or link only is not fine, but then the question is at fault and needs to be redone. Personally I'd say the question doesn't fit the site in the first place. It's quite like a 'where to buy' equivalent.

Comment: @Raffzahn The question asks for schematics. Per our rules, an answer would provide actual schematics, not (just) a description of where to find them.